# Laravel migrations - place column before another column

Tags: laravel

In Laravel we have an after() function that adds a column after a given column, for example :

```
  $table->string('address_line2')->after('address_line1');
```

I would like to add a before () function that would add a column before a given column. I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `before()` modifier after checking with the Laravel documentation. But you should know your fields in the table and its order so you can use `after()` modifier most of the time.

The only case that `after()` can't do is to add a field before the first field but there is `first()` modifier where you can put your field as the first field.